# Open whatsapp from website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

Consider the following html

```
<a class="whatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=.....">Share</a>
```

This will open my Whatsapp app as expected. What I need is the same thing but this time with javascript.

```
document.querySelector('.whatsapp').addEventListener('click', () => {
   // call whatsapp url, tried: fetch('whatsapp://...') -> error
})
```

How do I make that call, which should also work in IE11 :)

Comment: Assuming `whatsapp:` is an installed protocol, you should be able to do this with `window.open` or `location.href = ...` in response to a click: `document.querySelector('.whatsapp').addEventListener('click', function() {
       window.open("whatsapp://send?text=.....");
       /* or location.href = "whatsapp://send?text=....."; */
    });` If `whatsapp:` is not an installed protocol, you won't be able to trigger it in a cross-browser way. (Note that I changed the arrow function to a traditional function, since you mentioned IE11.)

Comment: Thnx, this indeed works. There is still one difference with the <anchor> way, which is that `window.open` creates a new tab and the anchor-way does not

Comment: `window.location.href`  is what I need, which was your other suggestion :)